# my car can't climb even a small ramp

Tags: engine, power, power-loss

I own a Toyota IQ model 2010

I have been experiencing this issue from the past year that my car when stopped on a small ramp it wouldn't even climb. Then I have to reverse all the way and get some momentum to climb the ramp.

I have shown it to a mechanic and cleaned all the spark plugs, oil filter, air filter, catalytic converter, fuel pump but none of these would repair my problem.

Also I noted my engine is reducing engine oil and my mechanic told me I had to change the engine block. So what do you guys suggest what should I get checked up because the aircon work perfect and my car speeds up pretty well but it has acceleration issues! Also my car vibrates alot when idle.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this an automatic or standard transmission? What does the vehicle do, exactly, when it won't climb the hill? Does the engine get faster, but the vehicle doesn't? Are there any weird sounds or smells when this happens? Are there oil spots where you park the vehicle? How many miles on the vehicle?

Comment: It is an automatic ! When my car has a momentum it can climb the hill or the slope but when i stop it on the slope on ramp no matter how much i accelerate the engine noise becomes heavy and it wont move . Yes the engine gets faster and vehicle doesnt move . When this happens there is no weird smell but the sound of engine struggling to get it going ! There are no oil spot on the floor but there are oil spot on the engine . The car is driven 150,000 Km . Its a japanese care . I live in pakistan and many mechanics over here dont understand cars like these . Please if u can help

Comment: Have you checked the transmission fluid (or have they)? It could be several things, but it most likely has something to do with your transmission. If the transmission fluid is low, it might be the culprit and an easy fix ... just get the fluid topped off and it should climb hills without an issue. However, if it is low, then you have to figure out where the fluid went to, which means there's a leak somewhere. If the fluid is burnt, it could mean your bands/clutches are slipping and might need a rebuild.

Comment: Thanx for you reply david . The mechanic recently cheaked the trasmission oil he told me that the transmission oil was very low like a litre left of 4 litres and it was very dirty . No doubt the car has been driven many years without changing the transmission oil and the mechanic told me there is no problem in the transmission as when i drive i dont feel jerks when the gears are changing(i dont trust mechanics here they lack knowledge). So i did change the transmission oil but it didnt get betten but got worse . Now the car doest speed up above 90km/h .

Comment: It doesnt speed above 90km/h . And when i try the RPM is stuck at 4000 rev and the engine noise gets heavy . I have no idea whats wrong with my car and the mechanic as well has no idea . Plz if u can help me so i can direct the mechanic what to do next .

Comment: It is a cvt automatic transmission

Comment: At this point, I'm betting your CVT belt is worn out.

Answer (score 1):

Have a mechanic do a compression check with a gauge.  It doesn't cost much (about $100 USD here in the USA) and doesn't require any more skill than changing spark plugs.  The results will tell you definitively if the engine block needs to be replaced.

The North American version of your car, the Toyota Scion, has had [a long history](https://repairpal.com/check-engine-light-due-to-defective-vvt-i-controller-976) of power/acceleration problems caused by a defective VVT-i controller, which changes cam timing for optimal power.  Most of these cases are accompanied by an illuminated Check Engine Light (CEL).  The repair is also not expensive, about $100 USD.

Other owners with model years 2007-2012 [have reported](https://www.carcomplaints.com/Scion/tC/2009/engine/engine.shtml) heavy oil consumption and power loss issues due to defective pistons made by Toyota.  There are no reports of a CEL, only low oil light on dashboard.  This issue seems to pertain to the 2az-fe engine.  Again, a compression check will tell if you have this problem.

If you have changed the transmission fluid (ATF) and the problem has gotten worse, try changing the fluid a least once more.  A neglected transmission, after changing the fluid, can suddenly dislodge sludge particles that clog the transmission.  Changing the fluid again can often clear the particles and restore transmission performance.  You may even have to change the fluid several more times every 1,000 km.